# Bootstrap : navbar items moving when I reduce the page width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two navbars, one above the other. This top bar is thinner with two nav items. These items are aligned on the right out the page. I have set it so that it does not collapse when the page width is reduced. However when I reduce the page too much the items seem to disapear, I believe it is moving down behind the other nav bar.

I would like it so those two nav items are just static on the page regardless of page width

**css:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 105px;
}

.navbar-top-custom {
    height: 28px;
    background-color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 1);
}

.navbar-bottom-custom {
    margin-top: 28px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 1);
}

.navbar-top-custom .nav-item{
    color: rgb(211, 211, 211) !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-top-custom fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>  Knowledge Base</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>  Client Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

full screen screenshot:

[image]

reduce width screenshot:

[image]

**Edit:**

So looking into it bootstrap seems to stack the `<li>` virtically when the resolution is reduce. Is there a way top prevent this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the issue with the `height` you've set for the `.navbar-top-custom`. Try removing the `height` and alter the `padding` of the `<nav>` or `<a>` instead.

Comment: When I do that and reduce the width it still aligns in a vertical fashion